# Why can't I ORDER BY in a Laravel Eloquent pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm curating my `posts` table on the home page to only show posts I've handpicked.

When I select a post for the home page, its ID goes into a `posts_homepage` table, which is basically a pivot table. I select the post's id (`post_id`) from `posts_homepage` and then get the posts from the `posts` table.

This is working just fine, however, now I want to put them in a particular order, so I've added an `order_by` field to `posts_homepage`. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get the result in the order I want, nothing's working; I'm just getting them in the default order.

```
TABLE posts_homepage
post_id    INT 10 UNSIGNED
order_by INT 10 UNSIGNED
```

Current query...

```
$posts = Post::latest('published_at')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('verified', 1);
    })
    ->whereRaw("posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM posts_homepage)")
    ->whereRaw("posts.status = 'published'")
    ->paginate(30);
```

I've tried removing `latest('published_at')` and inserting `->orderByRaw('ORDER BY posts_homepage.order_by ASC')`, but that didn't make a difference or I'd receive an error message `Unknown column 'posts_homepage.order_by' in 'order clause'`

I also tried `->whereRaw("posts.id IN (SELECT post_id FROM posts_homepage ORDER BY order_by ASC)")` but that didn't work either. I've tried a few other options as well, but can't get them returned based on the `order_by` field

Any suggestions?

Comment: You said `posts_homepage` is basically a pivot table, but pivot for which tables? I see it has only `post_id` as foreign key, so where is the other foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a simple join work here? For example:

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('verified', 1);
    })
    ->join('posts_homepage', 'posts.id', 'posts_homepage.post_id')
    ->where('posts.status', 'published')
    ->orderBy('posts_homepage.order_by', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(30);
```